# Как сделать текст как на картинке:

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать текст как на картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при Hover, она наполнялось цветом

**ЗАРАНЬЕ СПАСИБО**

Comment: Добро пожаловать в StackOverflow! Вопросы должны также содержать попытки автора решить задачу, без них ваш вопрос будет смотреться как задание которое вы просите сделать другого участника. Подробнее [в Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 500%;
}

div {
  transition: .5s;
  margin: auto;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px white;
}

div:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div>#QALAB</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать [text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke), если вас устроит его [поддержка браузерами](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke).

```css
body
{
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div
{
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #FFF;
  text-stroke: 1px #FFF;
  
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>#QALAB</div>
```